# Second Fundamental Form of Hypersurface Normal to Predefined Vector Field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, curvature

I am trying to compute the second fundamental form of a hypersurface that is normal to a predefined vector field. Any help would be appreciated.

More specifically, I consider a vector field $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Next, I fix a point $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and locally construct a surface that is normal to the vector field $\mathbf{v}$. Finally, I want to compute the second fundamental form in terms of $\mathbf{v}$.

In some cases, this is a trivial exercise if one can obtain the equations for the surface that is normal to the vector field $\mathbf{v}$. For example, if $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}$, the corresponding hypersurface is a hypersphere whose second fundamental form is easily determined. However, is there a way to obtain the second fundamental form by a direct calculation from the vector field $\mathbf{v}$? Also, is there a way to determine whether the second fundamental form is positive-definite (or negative-definite) based on some properties of the vector field $\mathbf{v}$?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet using the definition of the second fundamental form in terms of the Gauss map?

Comment: I thought a bit about that but I am not sure how to compute $d \mathbf{v}$ in the surface that is defined only implicitly. It is quite a while since I have done these things, which is the reason why I came for help :D

Comment: Here are some observations: 1) At each point, you know what the tangent space. 2) If you normalize the vector $\mathbf{v}$ to have unit length, then it is the Gauss map. 3) The second fundamental form is defined using the directional derivative of the Gauss map in the direction of a tangent vector.

Comment: Dear Deane, thank you very much - yes this is a good suggestion. I needed to return to my undergrad notes and it all makes sense now.